# My Asynctask is returning null

Tags: android

Why is my async task returning null? It was working perfectly before. What am I doing wrong?

I am a new developer, I don't have much knowledge how to fix this.

Here is my code.

```
private class PlayAudioFileBg extends AsyncTask<String, Object, MediaPlayer> {

    @Override
    protected MediaPlayer doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(params[0]);

            mMediaPlayer.prepare();

            return mMediaPlayer;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        super.onPostExecute(mediaPlayer);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            mSeekBar.setProgress(0, true);
        }else{
            mSeekBar.setProgress(0);
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mSeekBar.setEnabled(true);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(repeatTimes != 0){
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                }else{
                    releaseMediaPlayer();
                }

            }
        });
```

> Log Cat 08-22 09:51:04.279 11359-11359/com.example.android.top10music
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.android.top10music, PID: 11359
>                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.android.top10music.NarutoActivity$PlayAudioFileBg.onPostExecute(NarutoActivity.java:404)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.android.top10music.NarutoActivity$PlayAudioFileBg.onPostExecute(NarutoActivity.java:375)
>                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

Comment: Please explain in detail what you mean by "my async task returning null". An `AsyncTask` does not "return" anything. If you mean that `doInBackground()` is returning `null`, check LogCat, as you are catching an exception and logging the stack trace there.

Comment: Look inside logcat , you should find an exception. Or put breakpoint inside catch block and print e.getMessage()

Comment: post your log cat

Comment: Yes, the doInBackground  method is returning null

 my log cat is printing a NullPointerException

Comment: where is mediaPlayer defined as a variable?

Comment: @AbhijitChakra I posted.

Comment: @RayyanSiddiqui please mark an answer as accepted if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful when accessing variables in different threads. Change the `mMediaPlayer` variable to a local inside the `AsyncTask` rather than accessing the parent class.

```
@Override
    protected MediaPlayer doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(params[0]);

            mMediaPlayer.prepare();

            return mMediaPlayer;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that as soon as you try to access a variable from an inner class, the variable becomes `final` and therefore, in your `onExecute` you cannot assign anything to it. This causes an exception which you catch and eventually makes your code return null.